# How to wrap an interrupt vector table into an std::array?

Tags: c++, memory, microcontroller, interrupt, stdarray

I'm trying to abstract interrupt vector tables a little bit by having the same interface on multiple microcontrollers. 
ARM Cortex M3/4 devices seem to make it rather "easy" to relocate the interrupt vector table into ram.

Atmel ATmega328p-pu seems to not allow to relocate the vector table directly into RAM, but only to a specific location.

I'd like to wrap the existing interrupt vector table at 0x0 into a C++ std::array in order to easily access it and create an interface to easily register callback functions.

Best regards.

Comment: You might want to use `span` instead of `array`. That will only be available since C++20, but Boost [has it now](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__span.html). Or there's also [span-lite](https://github.com/martinmoene/span-lite), which is much lighter than Boost and might be preferable.

Comment: the ATmega328p does not support the C++ STL, thus raw pointer were lastly my choise.